# Trojan in the appcache how does that work?

Tags: windows-10, virus

I'm a bit confused about the behaviour of a virus (a trojan in this case). Specifically: Application.BitCoinMiner.SX

The forums of an online guild got hacked and the virus was put into the ad mechanism there. Virus scanners like avast didn't react to it and it managed to be put into the app cache of the PCs.

So far I understand what happened there. But now comes the strange part. ADAware that got installed didn't find it in quick scan but only in full scan which means that the virus was not active in the memory, but was still located in the app cache.

This is the part I'm not understanding. Regardless which virus or trojan for it to work it has to be loaded into the memory as far as I understand. This one was not.

So I'm wondering there how this works? (was that virus a remnant of something that used an already fixed browser weakness, ... or do viruses like this work in a way that I'm not expectig like needing you to visit specific web pages to do their work, ...).

Comment: not directly related to the question as is: I managed to remove that thing from the app cache at long last, but am thoroughly confused there as I never saw a virus that was not found in the memory of the PC it got onto. .

Comment: ... Or perhaps not a virus at all, just a false positive.

Comment: @MichaelBay Almost 100% that it is not a false positive as multiple visitors (including me) of the Forum of that guild had that positive with different Virus Scanners checking there. Also the Forums hoster officially stated that they were hacked and the Virus put onto their Servers. So 100% that ist not a false positive. Thus I'm not getting how that Virus could work there without being in Memory.